# Name for this Markov-like property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, terminology

Let $X_0, X_1,\ldots$ be a sequence of random variables on $(\Omega, \mathfrak A, P)$ taking values in a countable set $S\ne \emptyset.$ Consider the following two properties

1. For any $n=1, 2,\ldots$ and any values $i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_{n+1}\in S$ with $P(X_0=i_0, \ldots, X_n=i_n)>0$ it holds that 
   $$
   P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_n=i_n) = P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|X_n=i_n).
   $$
2. For any $n=1,2,\ldots$ it holds that 
   $$
   P(\cdot |X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1},X_n) = P(\cdot |X_n),
   $$
   where the two terms are the conditional probability measures on $\mathfrak A$ induced by $X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1},X_n$ and $X_n,$ respectively.

I've learned that $(X_n)$ is called a Markov Chain if it satisfies the first property. The second property also seems very natural. Is there a name for it? What is the relation between the Markov property and the second property?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you clarify the difference between the two cases? Are you removing the condition that state conditioned on has probability greater than zero, or are you generalizing the statement of the conditional probability?

Comment: Maybe an example of something that is not Markov but satisfies your condition (or the other way around) would be helpful.

Comment: The second property is rather odd (and not at all "Markov-like"). One can suspect that $$P(A\mid X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1},X_n)=P(A\mid X_n)$$ for every event $A$ and every $n$, if and only if the sigma-algebras $\sigma(X_n)$ and $\sigma(X_0)$ coincide, for every $n$.